# How do I construct this japanese bowl?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So I'm pretty new to Blender and I want to create a model of this Japanese bowls that aren't uniformly round, instead they have these larger polygons on the outside, as you can see in the picture.

I tried a few modifiers, but I couldn't find anything that would help. Does anyone have an idea how I could get this shape? Thanks.

[image: Picture of Japanese Bowl]

Comment: I don't think modifiers will give you the best results. Maybe 2.8 has something I don't know. Begin researching Blender sculpting and draw the specific pattern on paper to get your head around it beforehand. I'm watching for answers too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could try it this way:

- Put your picture as a *Background* image.

[image]

- Create a plane, rotate it on the X axis to have it in front view, apply the rotation.
- In *Front Ortho* view, use the picture as a model to build your mesh, mirror the mesh to make it easier.

[image]

- Switch to *Right Ortho* view and continue to model the mesh. You'll have to shift the mesh from its origin.

[image]

- Come back to *Object* mode. Create an empty at the same point as the object origin.

[image]

- Give your object an *Array* modifier, give it a Count of 8, deactivate *Relative Offset*, activate *Object Offset*, choose the empty as object.

[image]

- Rotate the empty 45° on the Z axis.

[image]

- In Edit mode, give some corrections to make the vertices stick approximately with their arrayed copies.

[image]

- Duplicate the empty + object to keep a copy somewhere on another layer.
- Apply the modifiers.
- Go in *Edit* mode, remove doubles.

[image]

- Dissolve the useless vertical edges.

[image]

- Make some corrections.

[image]

- Now you have your basic bowl. Of course you'll probably want it to be a bit more sophisticated, like adding some bevels, etc... in that case you can keep just 1/8 of the bowl and again spin it around the empy with an array, add your bevels on the original mesh, keep only quads, etc...

[image]

Comment: I'm replacing the word "amazing" today with "moonboots." That answer is super moonboots because the Japanese bowl shapes are non-standard. Though I wonder if "star" as a GD option might eventually get closer than the hex in the other answer.

Comment: oh thanks HelloHiHola! I don't think you can have this kind of complex pattern with Extra Objects but I never tried it so who knows?

Comment: I feel like this answer deserves more to be the accepted one, because it teaches a much more applicable concept than "just use this primitive".

Comment: it depends if he wants the exact pattern or something that mimics   ;)   Extra Objects seems convenient to quickly create something that looks like this pattern

Comment: great answer!!!

Comment: hey, thanks, this is an old one!

Answer (score 8):

Enable the "Add Mesh: Extra Objects" add-on and add a Geodesic Dome mesh.

Adjust the following:

Hedron: Icosahedron

Shape: hex

Frequency: as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A more simplistic variation: Create an icosphere, cut the top vertices off using edit mode.

OR...

Use the boolean modifier to cut the top off of an icosphere, then use another boolean with a normal sphere to hollow out the inside.

This might look a little rough, but I tend to be simplistic when modeling, if you get what I mean.